# Jade conditional based on page url?

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug

Is it possible to setup a jade conditional in my layout template based on page path? Is there a page path variable? I am looking to do things like:

```
if page = "/about"
  link(rel='stylesheet', href='css/about')
else
  link(rel='stylesheet', href='css/main')
```

Where this is part of the layout template. Where and how do I define the variables to drive this?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it is possible:

```
- var page = window.location.pathname

if page === "/about"
   link(rel='stylesheet', href='css/about.css')
else
   link(rel='stylesheet', href='css/main.css')
```

Please note that above snippet assumes the template is executed in browser environment. If this is not the case, you can get the pathname using the language that you are using and pass it to the template as a datum. As an example, if you are using the Express framework, [`path`](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#req.path) property of the `request` object returns the path part of the URL.

Comment: This solution assumes the template is being executed within the browser and not server-side.

Comment: @cspotcode Yes, it does. Maybe because I'm used to develop SPAs. I'll update. Thanks!

Comment: I am not using any framework - this is for a couple of static pages for a website.  The back end cms is craft , if that helps. So not sure the template is executed in the browser ( not sure what that means, btw)

Comment: @user2022284 The "back-end" implies that the template is executed on the server-side and not on the browser. You should get the path using your "cms" (_whatever it is_) and pass it to the template. Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17184791/node-js-url-parse-and-pathname-property

Answer (score 1):

I would set the path dynamically with req.path in express:

```
res.locals.path = req.path;
res.render('about');
```

and then using path in jade file:

```
if path === "/about/"
   link(rel='stylesheet', href='css/about.css')
else
   link(rel='stylesheet', href='css/main.css')
```

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your setup

In express:

```
res.locals.cssPath = 'css/about.css';
res.render('about');
```

Jade:
Not sure about the syntax here since i don't use jade but you have access to locals

```
link(rel='stylesheet', href=cssPath)
```