# Node.js how to split querystring value by index

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to figure out how to split a querystring's values in Node.js. This is for a web proxy I am creating. I need to split the querystring by the third '/' for example. `https://example.org/bahahhaah` to `https://example.org`. It will also be nice if I knew how to split by the last one for example `https://example.org/bahhaa/s2.html` to `https://example.org/bahhaa`. I wanna have these two outputs save into a cookie. I am not sure what code to put for example. If I am not being clear enough, please tell me.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for, is the built-in Node.js module `URL`. It will parse things out [see this question's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17184791/node-js-url-parse-and-pathname-property), so you can get the pathname. Then, you can `.split` the pathname to find the things you are looking for:

```js
const url = require('url');
const URLparts = url.parse('https://example.org/bahahhaah').pathname.split('/');

console.log(URLParts); // yields [`bahahhaah`]
```

`URLParts` now yields an array of your path parts, separated by the / at the end of the URL.